# SQL Server sequence set current value

Tags: sql-server, sequence

I am using SQL Server 2012 (v11.0.2100) and I want to create a sequence that starts with a random (dynamic) number but I wasn't able to do this, also I put my effort to find a good solution for this but I haven't found something that will satisfy me.

The case that I tried and failed:

```
 DECLARE @sth bigint

 SET @sth = 1000

 ALTER SEQUENCE StreamEntrySequence
 RESTART WITH @sth;
```

Error :

> Incorrect syntax near '@sth'

An ugly solution

```
 declare @sth bigint;
 declare @i bigint;

 SET @sth = 100000    ; 

 while @i<@sth;
 BEGIN
    SET @i= next value for StreamEntrySequence;
 END
```

Is there other way to set the current value or the start value to a random value? Maybe using server procedures?

Comment: What is the point of restarting a sequence with a random number? That seems rather strange. You would need to use dynamic sql for this. I would run away quickly from using a loop like that.

Comment: @SeanLange The point is to synchronize the sequence with the actual last value in the database. This can be done, for example, after the sequence is first added to an existing system, and used to synchronize the **next sequence number** to the last **identity** value. The number isn't random; it's a `StreamEntryID`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As has been mentioned, this would require dynamic SQL since [alter sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878572.aspx) requires a constant for the `restart` argument.

You might do something like this, then:

```
DECLARE @sth bigint;
SET @sth = 1000;
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
SET @sql = N'ALTER SEQUENCE StreamEntrySequence RESTART WITH ' + cast(@sth as nvarchar(20)) + ';';
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql;
```

Comment: I already have 2 tables with data that are FK in other tables. I want this 2 tables to use a shared sequence so both of them will have different and unique IDs. For one of them for the existing data I am able to reset the primary key to new values, but for the other one no.

Comment: Thanks Tim Lehner, I totally forgot about execute sql. I am using too much EF :))

Comment: Seems like a better implementation would have been for Microsoft to simply allow the use of variables when creating or altering a sequence... this answer does get me what I need but it's unfortunate having to resort to dynamic sql only to create a sequence with a START value based on a variable.  Again... this does work beautifully so thank you for that!

Answer (score 18):

Try

```
ALTER SEQUENCE foo.fee
RESTART
```

Or:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE foo.fee
RESTART WITH 1
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878572.aspx